# Accessing properties from prototype triggered by EventEmitter

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to write a simple class to trigger prototype functions when an event is received, however I'm having an issue with scope. For some reason, I can't access the `Stream` context, even though I've bound my event listeners to it.

```
function Stream(report) {
  this.report = report;

  this.stream = new api.getTagStream(report.tag);
  this.stream.on('error', this.onError.bind(this));
  this.stream.on('data', this.onData.bind(this));

  return this;
}

Stream.prototype.onError = err => {
  // Had an error
}

Stream.prototype.onData = data => {
  console.log(this.report); // undefined
}

new Stream({ tag: 'sometag' });
```

Log within `onData` should display the report object, however returns undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace arrow function with "normal" function declaration

```
function Stream(report, stream) {
  this.report = report
  stream.on('error', this.onError.bind(this))
  stream.on('data', this.onData.bind(this))
}

Stream.prototype.onData = function(data) {
  console.log(this.report, data) // { tag: 'some tag' } 'some passed data'
}

const EventEmitter = require('events')
const stream = new EventEmitter()

new Stream({ tag: 'some tag' }, stream)

stream.emit('data', 'some passed data')
```